# How do I get the ticket in ticket lake?

Tags: pony-island

I don't want to go ahead too far, for fear of being unable to come back. How do I get to the ticket?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the stage to the top right of the lake, then click on the stage below the lake and then quickly click on the square to the left of that one whilst the pony is still moving. This will cause the pony to walk across the lake.